# Padding arrays and turning hashes into arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

If I have a hash `{:one => [1,2,3,4], :two => [6,7,8]}` how can I just make an array where Array[0] = [1,6], [1] = [2,7], [2] = [3,8], [3] = [4,nil]`` ?

Comment: Why do you skip `[1]`? I cannot get the rule.

Comment: Whoops! Fixed! I didn't watch Sesame Street as a kid =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With **zip**:

```
h = {:one => [1,2,3,4], :two => [6,7,8]}
h[:one].zip h[:two] # => [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, nil]]
```

For any number of keys:

```
h = {:one => [1,2,3,4], :two => [6,7,8], :three => [9,10]}
vals = h.values # => [[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
vals[0].zip *vals[1..-1] # => [[1, 6, 9], [2, 7, 10], [3, 8, nil], [4, nil, nil]]
```

However I don't believe the order of these is guaranteed (because hashes are unordered). You might want to consider a different approach. (As David points out in the comments, Hashes are actually ordered in Ruby 1.9, so this isn't a concern.)

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to zip everything without knowing how many keys there will be in the has? (This could be up to :fiftythree, :two, :ten, etc).

Comment: @jtbandes> Hashes *are* ordered since Ruby 1.9 . Just to be precise.